# Is onChanged() callback the only way to access LiveData object contents

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room, android-livedata, android-architecture-components

I have a query which returns some notes (with field name like some text)

```
//MY DAO
 @Query("SELECT * FROM note_table WHERE name LIKE :text_name")
DataSource.Factory<Integer, Note> getSomePagedNotes(String text_name);
```

So in my ViewModel I have the LiveData

```
//RETURNS LIVEDATA
public LiveData<PagedList<Note>> getMyPagedNotes(String text_name){
    DataSource.Factory<Integer, Note> data   = noteDao.getSomePagedNotes(text_name);
    LiveData<PagedList<Note>> dataList   = new LivePagedListBuilder(data, 50).build();
    return dataList;
}
```

Yeah so somewhere in my Activity/Fragment I have the Observer with OnChanged , I can Observe the data and it works .

**My Question is : Is there another way to parse (query) the getMyPagedNotes Results directly without setting up an observer?**

Comment: Add a second DAO function that returns `List<Note>`. Or, consume the `DataSource.Factory` directly yourself.

Comment: Hi @ CommonsWare When I return List<Note> I have to do Async actions and it is a bother, I am interested in consuming DataSource.Factory directly do you have docs about it or more details

Comment: "When I return List<Note> I have to do Async actions and it is a bother" -- anything else involves some sort of callback, such as the `Observer` that you are trying to avoid. And, you would need to "do Async actions" to consume the `DataSource` created by the `DataSource.Factory`. The DAO function should return a factory for a `PositionalDataSource`, and you can [see its API](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/paging/PositionalDataSource.html).

Comment: Ok @CommonsWare Thank you very much for your very useful response I will make sure to check the doc you mentionned.